# ¿Cómo puedo fijar el tamaño de una celda de un THEAD muy extenso de 36 columnas y dos filas?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, tablas

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>        
                <th rowspan="2">1</th>
                <th rowspan="2">2</th>
                <th rowspan="2">3</th>
                <th rowspan="2">4</th>
                <th rowspan="2">5</th>
                <th rowspan="2">6</th>
                <th rowspan="2">7</th>
                <th colspan="2">8</th>
                <th colspan="4">Factor</th>
                <th rowspan="2">9</th>
                <th colspan="3">10</th>
                <th rowspan="2">11</th>
                <th colspan="3">12</th>
                <th colspan="5">13</th>
                <th rowspan="2">14</th>
                <th colspan="2">15</th>
                <th colspan="4">15</th>
                <th rowspan="2">17</th>
                <th rowspan="2">18</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <th>t</th>
                 <th>uOtro</th>
                 <th>No. j</th>
                 <th>j</th>
                 <th>h</th>
                 <th>g</th>
                 <th>g de w</th>
                 <th>fde h</th>
                 <th>y</th>
                 <th>No.</th>
                 <th>w</th>
                 <th>Tipo</th>
                 <th>Esta 4</th>
                 <th>Esta w</th>
                 <th>Se Aplica</th>
                 <th>Es r</th>
                 <th>ede la edel control</th>
                 <th>ede impacto</th>
                 <th>ede Ocurrencia</th>
                 <th>I</th>
                 <th>II</th>
                 <th>III</th>
                 <th>IV</th>
           </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Cual es el th que quieres modificar y de que tamaño lo quieres?

Comment: el que tiene el numero 3!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo agregando una clase especifica al `th` que desees.  Te dejo un ejemplo:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grande {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>        
                <th rowspan="2">1</th>
                <th rowspan="2">2</th>
                <th rowspan="2" class="grande">3</th>
                <th rowspan="2">4</th>
                <th rowspan="2">5</th>
                <th rowspan="2">6</th>
                <th rowspan="2">7</th>
                <th colspan="2">8</th>
                <th colspan="4">Factor</th>
                <th rowspan="2">9</th>
                <th colspan="3">10</th>
                <th rowspan="2">11</th>
                <th colspan="3">12</th>
                <th colspan="5">13</th>
                <th rowspan="2">14</th>
                <th colspan="2">15</th>
                <th colspan="4">15</th>
                <th rowspan="2">17</th>
                <th rowspan="2">18</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <th>t</th>
                 <th>uOtro</th>
                 <th>No. j</th>
                 <th>j</th>
                 <th>h</th>
                 <th>g</th>
                 <th>g de w</th>
                 <th>fde h</th>
                 <th>y</th>
                 <th>No.</th>
                 <th>w</th>
                 <th>Tipo</th>
                 <th>Esta 4</th>
                 <th>Esta w</th>
                 <th>Se Aplica</th>
                 <th>Es r</th>
                 <th>ede la edel control</th>
                 <th>ede impacto</th>
                 <th>ede Ocurrencia</th>
                 <th>I</th>
                 <th>II</th>
                 <th>III</th>
                 <th>IV</th>
           </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```